# Confusion with viewset in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was learning Viewset in Django Rest framework and found out that we need to add these variables:

```
queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

inside viewset or say ModelViewSet to be exact. THe question is why need queryset and serializer_class variables in ModelViewSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that's how your ViewSet can return any data. It uses the `queryset` to get the data to/from the database, and the `serializer_class` to un-/serialise the data. The ViewSet defines behaviours around those two things, e.g. how it will get what data for `GET` requests and how it will accept and store data for `POST`/`PUT`/`DELETE` requests.

Answer (score 1):

```
queryset - We need queryset in order to get the data from database table

serializer_class - We need to have serializer, so that it can convert the data into json (Rest API).
```

Comment: hey)),  ok, I understood serializer_class and it is used with put, post and delete methods because we send data to the server and  serializer_class helps to deserialize and then put data into database. Is that correct? As for queryset, is it used when we send get request to the server. Right?